# How are COM objects marshalled between application domain?

Tags: c#, .net, com

Out of curiosity - I've been wondering, how are [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) objects in C# marshalled across [application domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain)?

To my understanding, they can't be marshalled by reference (not deriving from MarshalByRefObject). I doubt they're serializable, so not by value either - which would only leave by bleed. Is that's what's happening? Or is there anything else at work?

I have found no information about that anywhere. I've basically just seen by trial and error that passing these over just... works. But I don't know why/how, and if that holds true for any COM object.

Are there any particular pitfalls to mind when passing these along application domains - e.g., would they need to be released explicitly on every domain that uses them?

Comment: According to the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242391/does-com-interop-respect-net-appdomain-boundaries-for-assembly-loading) _"A COM component is loaded within Process Space and not within the context of an AppDomain"_

Comment: AppDomains only provide isolation for managed objects, a COM object is not.  Furthermore, the managed wrapper for a COM interface (derived from `System.__ComObject`) *does* in fact derive from MarshalByRefObject.  See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__comobject.cs,28  So it just works.

Comment: Thanks both of you, that is highly interesting, I didn't know this. Happy to tag either of this as an answer if posted as such - thank you! Given it is a MarshalByRefObject, I suppose I will need to consider lifetime management for these as usual (register sponsors etc.)